# differences between form's post action and ajax's post type

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I think

```
<form action="some.php" method="POST">...</form>
```

and

```
$.ajax({
   type:POST,
   url:some.php,
//...
});
```

both do the same thing, but I can't make the latter redirect me to some.php whereas the former automatically load the page after the post is done. Which one to you is more preferred ? Are they really the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire point of AJAX is that you aren't forced to load a different page into the browser when using it.

Answer (score 2):

wow ... this is the first time in my Ajax history someone actually WANTS his page to be refreshed by an Ajax call. This is usually the situation one wants to avoid.

Conclusion: There is no point in using Ajax if you want to redirect your browser after sending POST data